# add default path of GSL for gcc(g++) compiler on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc

system: Ubuntu 14.04
I download a GSL(GNU Scientific Library) and it is correctly installed on my computer, in directory /home/chenjiyao/GSL

Then I add a few lines at the buttom of `~/.bashrc`

`export PATH=$PATH:/home/chenjiyao/GSL/bin`

`export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:/home/chenjiyao/GSL/include`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/chenjiyao/GSL/lib`

then I just `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal.

But it seems not working because when I `include<gsl/gsl_math.h>` in the source file, I was told that the head file is not found, which means the path for gcc is not settled correctly.

What's wrong with it ?

Thank you.

Comment: What about include<gsl_math.h> ?

Comment: actually, the head file `gsl_math.h` is in the directory `/home/chenjiyao/GSL/include/gsl`, so we have to `include<gsl/gsl_math.h>`. Thank you.